# VBA Determine XSD Element "Name"

Tags: xml, vba, xsd

I am using Access/VBA to allow a user to upload an XML file to build a database structure. This the current code I have that will properly give me the _Map name I need for doing later steps to upload XML data into the database from XLS/XML overlay'd files:
Code:

```
Dim myFolder As String
    Form_frmImportSurveyData.txtFile.SetFocus
    myDir = Form_frmImportSurveyData.txtFile.Text

    Dim xmlDom As New DOMDocument
    xmlDom.Load (myDir)

    xmlMap = xmlDom.DocumentElement.nodeName
```

This code gives me the parent node name that I need... for example with an XML structure of
Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Survey xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Surveyor></Surveyor>
    <Date></Date>
    <Cascade></Cascade>
.......
</Survey>
```

it will return 'Survey' which is what I need it to do.

What i now want to do is allow users the option to build a database structure from an XML Schema File (.XSD) so that the database is build better (date/time) fields, etc will be created instead of all text fields, etc. What I need to know how to do what i listed above with extracting an XSD file instead of an XML file... my XSD code looks like this:
Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Survey">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Surveyor" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="Date" type="xs:date" />
                <xs:element name="Cascade" />
.....
       </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

If I use the current line in the vba code i have now:
Code:

```
xmlMap = xmlDom.DocumentElement.nodeName
```

and modify it to:
Code:

```
xmlDom.DocumentElement.FirstChild.nodeName
```

(returns 'xs:element')

OR
Code:

```
xmlDom.DocumentElement.FirstChild.BaseName
```

(returns 'element')

What do I need to do in order to have 'Survey' returned within this line of XSD:
Code:

```
<xs:element name="Survey">
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
xmlDom.DocumentElement.FirstChild.GetAttribute("Name")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct answer:

```
xmlDom.DocumentElement.FirstChild.Attributes.getNamedItem("name").NodeValue
```